# Mongodb, Node - Updating multiple objects synchronously

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, async.js

Using Mongodb, Nodejs, Async.js and Express.js

I am trying to update multiple documents, where each document has its own update, at the same time. I want to wait for all documents to update so that I can notify user that all documents have updated.

The issue I am having now is that my callback function is not firing, or if it is, then nothing is happening. Here is my progress:

```
db.client.collection('page').find({page_id: page_id}).toArray(function(page_err, document_page) {
    if(page_err) {
        throw page_err;
    } else if(document_page === '' || document_page === undefined || document_page === null) {
        throw page_err;
    } else {
        var count = 0;
        async.each(data, function iteratee(i, callback) {
            var item_id = (i.item_id === '') ? new ObjectId() : new ObjectId(i.item_id);
            var query = {item_id: item_id};
            var update = {
                _id : new ObjectId(),
                page_id : page_id,
                section_id : null,
                item_id : item_id,
                created : new Date().toISOString(),
                item_type : "dish",
                item: {
                    title: i.title,
                    description: i.description,
                    price: i.price,
                    star: false,
                    double_star: false
                },
                last_modified: new Date().toISOString()
            };
            var options = { upsert: true };

            db.client.collection('item').updateOne(query, {$set: update}, options, function(item_err, results) {
                if(item_err) {
                    res.sendStatus(500);
                } else if(results === '' || results === undefined || results === null) {
                    res.sendStatus(400);
                } else {
                    ++count;
                    if(count === data.length) {
                        callback();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            });
        }, function() {
            console.log('sending 200 status');
            res.sendStatus(200);
        });
    }
});
```

When I run the code I do enter the if statement where I call callback(). I have been stuck on this for a few hours and I cannot get it to work. If you need more info, I'd be happy to provide it. For simplicity's sake I removed many console.logs to avoid clutter as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All iterations need to fire the callback otherwise it will hang indefinitely. `callback` must be called in every iteration. Always.

If you encounter an error, you need to call `callback(error)`. The problem you'll have is that async.each schedules all iterations beforehand so `iteratee` will fire `data.length` times regardless of whether an error is encountered half way through execution or not. If you need to run them in series you can use `async.eachSeries` which will take more time but gives you better control and no need to rollback.

So code wise it looks like this:

```
    db.client.collection('page').find({page_id: page_id}).toArray(function(page_err, document_page) {
        if(page_err) {
            throw page_err;
        } else if(document_page === '' || document_page === undefined || document_page === null) {
            throw page_err;
        } else {
            async.each(data, function iteratee(i, callback) {
                var item_id = (i.item_id === '') ? new ObjectId() : new ObjectId(i.item_id);
                var query = {item_id: item_id};
                var update = {
                    _id : new ObjectId(),
                    page_id : page_id,
                    section_id : null,
                    item_id : item_id,
                    created : new Date().toISOString(),
                    item_type : "dish",
                    item: {
                        title: i.title,
                        description: i.description,
                        price: i.price,
                        star: false,
                        double_star: false
                    },
                    last_modified: new Date().toISOString()
                };
                var options = { upsert: true };

                db.client.collection('item').updateOne(query, {$set: update}, options, function(item_err, results) {
                    if(item_err) {
                        callback(500);
                    } else if(results === '' || results === undefined || results === null) {
                        callback(400)
                    } else {
                        callback();
                    }
                });
            }, function(err) {
                // Passing the status code only for the example.
                // `err` should be an object with more metadata probably
                if(err) {
                    res.sendStatus(err);
                    return;
                }
                console.log('sending 200 status');
                res.sendStatus(200);
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but this worked. Thanks a bunch! Like you said, I was lacking the callbacks in the rest of the application flow